# How can i get rid of the bar at the top side?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-actionbar, version, appcompatactivity

So I am a begginer at android app developing, and I want to find a way to get rid of the blue bar that appears in every screen. Or will it get removed by it self when I launch in actual phone? Help me please!

to be more precise, when I name my project name for example cupcake, a blue bar that is written cupcake on it, shows up on top of every screen.

Comment: This is called the Actionbar or Toolbar. You should really start with reading some android documentation and learning about general UI and usability, and to get rid of it you should look up what themes are

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding this to your class extends Activity than

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);
    getActionBar().hide();
```

if activity extends **AppCompatActivity**

than use `getSupportActionBar().hide();`

Comment: when I typed this, the app just failed.. couldn't see any red error though.

Comment: what you have typed ? what it extends ?

Comment: in AndroidMenifest use  android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"

Comment: i had to import android.view.Window;   andthen..                                                                                                     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);
   getSupportActionBar().hide();

Comment: that made no sense let try your last comment

Answer (score 0):

**In Programatically you can do this**

Put this code in onCreate method of your Actvity before setting content view -

```
getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);
getSupportActionBar().hide();
```

**Or you can Change the theme in Android Manifest file**

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
```